# Distriqt AIR Local Notification Ane - Delete old Notifications

Tags: mobile, air, notifications, push-notification, local

we try to implement the nice local notifications extension of distriqt.

With the deactivate event new notifications were set:

```
 notification.id        = int(Math.random()*100);
                    notification.tickerText = _asde + " asdasd!";
                    notification.title      = _asde + " asd!";
                    notification.body       = "asd!";
                    notification.iconType   = NotificationIconType.APPLICATION;
                    notification.count      = 0;
                    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
                    notification.vibrate    = false;
                    notification.playSound  = true;
                    notification.soundName  = "assets/sounds/notification.mp3";

                    notification.delay      = secondsToDeath;
                    notification.data       = "Some notification data to attach "+notification.id;
try
                {
                    Notifications.service.notify( notification.id, notification );

                    _count ++;
                    Notifications.service.setBadgeNumber( _count );
                }
                catch (e:Error)
                {

                }
```

If the user clicks on the app and deactivates it again, new notifications were set.

The old notifications are still available and are displayed but we want the old to be deleted. 
We haven't found a method to unregister the old notifications.

Any idea?

```
        private static const DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID_4 : int = 4;
```

Is declared.

```
if(_GoodA == true){
                    setSpielenFertigDate.time = 2400000*(1-_aktuellerFreudeWert/_maximalerFreudeWert);
                    var secondsToSpielenFertig:int = int((setSpielenFertigDate.time)/ 1000);

                    trace("halloe" + _fernseherAn.toString());
                    notification4.id        = DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID_4;
                    notification4.tickerText = "He test it!";
                    notification4.title         = "sdf is happy!";
                    notification4.body      = "sdf test is on!";
                    notification4.iconType  = NotificationIconType.APPLICATION;
                    notification4.count     = 0;
                    notification4.repeatInterval = 0;
                    notification4.vibrate   = false;
                    notification4.playSound  = true;
                    notification4.soundName  = "assets/sounds/notification.mp3";

                    notification4.delay     = secondsToSpielenFertig;
                    notification4.data      = "Some notification data to attach "+ notification4.id;

                    try
                    {
                        Notifications.service.notify( notification4.id, notification4 );

                        _count ++;
                        Notifications.service.setBadgeNumber( _count );
                    }
                    catch (e:Error)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else{
                    trace("halloe2" + _fernseherAn.toString());
                    setSpielenDate.time = 5100000*(_aktuellerFreudeWert/_maximalerFreudeWert);
                    var secondsToSpielen:int = int((setSpielenDate.time)/ 1000);


                    notification4.id        = DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID_4;
                    notification4.tickerText = "He tested it!";
                    notification4.title         = "sdf is unhappy!";
                    notification4.body      = "sdf test is off!";
                    notification4.iconType  = NotificationIconType.APPLICATION;
                    notification4.count     = 0;
                    notification4.repeatInterval = 0;
                    notification4.vibrate   = false;
                    notification4.playSound  = true;
                    notification4.soundName  = "assets/sounds/notification.mp3";
                    //Sekunden bis Nachricht geschickt wird
                    notification4.delay     = secondsToSpielen;
                    notification4.data      = "Some notification data to attach "+notification4.id;

                    try
                    {
                        Notifications.service.notify( notification4.id, notification4 );

                        _count ++;
                        Notifications.service.setBadgeNumber( _count );
                    }
                    catch (e:Error)
                    {

                    }
                }
```

If the deactivate event of the app is fired it traces the correct part of the if and else clause. But it won't update the body and title...

Comment: Are you on iOS or Android?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this with our extension. Both involve tracking the ID of the notification.

The first is to track your last notification and "cancel" it from the notification area. To do this you need to store at least the ID of the last created notification. The part of the code that you're probably interested in is the **cancel** function, this removes a notification from the notification panel by specifying the id of the notification to remove.

Somewhere in your class declare a reference to the last notification:

```
private var _lastNotification : Notification;
```

Then in your deactivate handler:

```
var notification:Notification = new Notification();
notification.id = int(Math.random()*100);
notification.tickerText = "Deactivated";
notification.title = "TEST";
notification.body = "Application Deactivated";

if (_lastNotification != null)
    Notifications.service.cancel( _lastNotification.id );
Notifications.service.notify( notification.id, notification );

// Set this to be the recent notification displayed
_lastNotification = notification;
```

The second option is to use a single notification id for all of your deactivate notifications. In this case you choose a constant ID to use for your notification and update the notification as required. The notification manager will not show an additional notification but simply update the one with the specified ID (or show it if it has been closed by the user).

```
private static const DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID : int = 10;

var notification:Notification = new Notification();
notification.id = DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID;
notification.tickerText = "Deactivated";
notification.title = "TEST";
notification.body = "Application Deactivated";

Notifications.service.notify( notification.id, notification );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It is the second part that I was looking for. I know the cancel function, but it is not possible to delete the active Notifications with this. So I had to overwrite the values. It updates the Notification.delay now. But it does not update the Notification.body?

Comment: How could I update the Notification.body and Notification.title?

Comment: If you're using the constant ID method then just specifying a new body and title in the new notification should update the existing notification of the same ID.

Comment: The strange thing is that the delay is updated but the body and title not.
Could I try to make this:
Notifications.service.notify(notification.id, null) and then set it again? Does this make a sense?

Comment: Did you try a call to Notifications.service.cancel( DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID_4 ) before calling notify again?

Comment: What device and OS version are you using?

Comment: If I set the delay everywhere to 0 seconds everything works as expected. But if the delay is changed to another value, the message appears after the correct delay but the title and body weren't updated. Using Samsung Galaxy SII with Android 4.0.4. In the activate listener of the app we call the cancelAll() method

Comment: We tested to call Notifications.service.cancel( DEACTIVATE_NOTIFICATION_ID_4 ) before calling notify again and it doesn't work...

Comment: We commented the .sound, .count, .RepeatInterval, .vibrate, .playSound, .soundName, .data and .setBadgeNumber out. No success.

Comment: Ah right, so the delay is causing the problem? I'll have a look into why that would be.

Comment: I've isolated the problem and have updated the package. You can download the updated package through the link you got when you downloaded the package. Email me if you've lost it. The Notifications extension should now be at "1.3.Android.1.4".

Comment: We will buy the extension again to support and thank for your support :D I hope this is already included in the ane?

Comment: You don't need to buy again, we include all upgrades and updates in the extension package! :) Just grab the update from the same place you originally downloaded.

Comment: We bought the extension again...unfortunately there are still notifications that were shown although they should have been overwritten.

Comment: Sorry can you please explain more, what you mean by "should have been overwritten"? Are you getting multiple notifications using the same ID?

Comment: I have the feeling that sometimes the notifications were not updated. It is not very often but sometimes the wrong notificaion is displayed. In our app all notifications are canceled on viewActivate and we set new notifications on viewDeactivate. We aways use the same ids so that the old notifications should be overwritten. See the if else part above.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to make a method that can be called and this really cancels/deletes all notifications that are set before?

Comment: Have you tried this without cancelling the notification? If you can send me the complete code sample that reproduces this error I'll try and track down what is happening in your case.